# Hex/binary editor with tagging (highlight a section and store that highlight persistently)

Tags: windows, hex-viewer, binary-data

I am looking for a binary editor (Hex editor with binary view) that supports tags – i.e. the ability to highlight a section and store that highlight persistently.

[image: WxHex window showing tagging feature]
<sup>tags example (screenshot from *WxHex;* click image for larger variant)</sup>

Editors I have tried:

- WxHex: Great, but does not have any binary view.
- 010 Editor: Supports binary view, but does not have tags, nor can you
  even highlight a set of bits, only bytes.
- Hex Editor Neo: Same as 010 Editor
- HxD: Does not support binary view or tags
- UltraEdit: Does not have binary view or Tags

If anyone has more ideas, I would appreciate them greatly!

Comment: [Cutter](https://cutter.re/), [Hexinator](https://hexinator.com/) and [Binary Ninja](https://binary.ninja/) all have this feature.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning other good hexeditors; WxHex was quite suitable for me.

Comment: @AlessandroGhio, post it as an answer

Comment: [ImHex](https://github.com/WerWolv/ImHex) is a nice hex editor with tagging, but no binary view at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: @AlessandroGhio I don't see any way to show a binary view or do tagging/highlighting in Cutter.